# Downloading zip with c#

Tags: c#, web, webclient

After download my file is 1kb and zip demaged

I've tried WebCliet but it doesn't work anyone have solution for this?

My code is:

```
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://supersite.io/file.zip"), "File.zip");
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Try open the file with a text editor (notepad will do). I bet it's html with an error text.

Answer (score 1):

The method `DownloadFileAsync` works in the background. It doesn't wait for the download to finish before executing the rest of the code.

Use `DownloadFile` if you want to wait for the download to finish.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(new Uri("http://supersite.io/file.zip"), "File.zip");
```

If you want to have the download happen in the background you have to explain a bit more about the background of your application. Is it a console application, WinForms UI or what other type of application?

---

Also, you should specify a full path for the download target. The file would otherwise be placed at a random place, possibly in a folder where you don't have write access.

For example when you have a c:\Temp folder

```
client.DownloadFile(new Uri("http://supersite.io/file.zip"), "C:\\Temp\\File.zip");
```

Comment: it doesn't work anyway

Comment: same file has 1kb

Comment: "The file would otherwise be placed at a random place" - I can't imagine it's a *random* place. Most likely it's going to be the current working directory.

Comment: file is corrupted

Comment: @Axene If you need more help, provide the actual code you use with the real download link. Also look inside the downloaded file. Is there some readable text?